# lost all apps icons on the pin

Tags: pin-to-start

The all apps icons missing on the first page  ,including  setting icons. After search in store , they have installed already. I cannot uninstall as well. They never show in the list
I soft reset but they still missing . How I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: What phone do you have? What version of Windows Phone or Windows 10 Mobile is it running? What icons exactly are missing? From the Start screen or from the all apps list? How and when did the problem start?

Comment: Are you able to swipe to the left to see the "Installed Apps" list? Nevertheless, the infos that @Indrek asked for are needed anyways.